# What are the products of the double displacement reaction of oxalic acid and cesium hydroxide?

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, ionic-compounds

A solution of oxalic acid is mixed with a solution of cesium hydroxide. This chemical reaction requires double displacement. I got this as my chemical equation:

$$\ce{C2H2O4 + CsOH -> H3O + CsC2O4}$$

My teacher says it is wrong, is it really incorrect?

Is the one below the right one?

$$\ce{C2H2O4 + CsOH -> CsHC2O4 + H2O}$$

Comment: I would start by considering what the products are. This is a special type of double displacement; it would probably also help for you to identify which one.

Answer (score 3):

You have a dicarboxylic acid (Oxalic Acid) reacting with a base (Cesium Hydroxide). This reaction will give you a carboxylate salt (Cesium Oxalate) and water. This is basically a neutralization reaction.

$$\ce{C2H2O4 + 2CsOH -> C2Cs2O4 + 2H2O}$$

You need 2 Cesium cations to neutralize the -2 charge of the dicarboxylic acid.

Here is an image of how Cesium oxalate looks like:

[image: Structure of Cesium oxalate]